# why onPassivate() method called multiple times in Tapestry5

Tags: tapestry

when i click on some pageLink then it goes to the dedicated page provided in the pagelink. 
but on the dedicated page onPassivate() method called multiple times.

anybody knows why?

Regards,
Mahendra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

onPassivate is called every time a link to that page is created. So if your page holds a couple of event/page links to itself, onPassivate is called once for each link. This is outlined in the [tapestry documentation](http://tapestry.apache.org/page-navigation.html#PageNavigation-PageRenderRequests).